# C:exit case in switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

i just have a quick question regarding the switch case.
can I do this? I can't get it to work. the program just says invalid 3 times when i type quit.
excuse the pseudo code.
oops i forgot to mention that the printf function looks like this before that part.

```
char choice;
printf("list, add, delete, write, quit\n");

do
{
scanf("%c", &choice);
//if (&choice== "quit"){exit(1);}

switch(choice)
    {
        case "list":
        case "add":
        case "delete":
        case "write":
        default:
            printf("Invalid\n");
            break;
        case "quit":
        exit (1);

    }while(&choice !="quit");
```

}

Comment: This is not valid C and should not even compile. Neither arrays nor pointers are valid case labels.

Comment: @R.. So, the program's output is actualy correct, isn't it?

Comment: @panda of course. This isn't a bug in your compiler or something.

Comment: i forgot to mention the printf function before that. sorry

Comment: This code snippet has lots of issues: some instructions are in the wrong order (copy-paste mistake), you're reading a single char and comparing to a string, the comparison itself is wrong because it's comparing addresses...

Comment: You could a character ever be equal to "list"?

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare strings like that. String comparison should be done with `strcmp` and its kin. In this case, you're comparing the addresses of the strings.

Comment: This answer is wrong (its third=last sentence only).  @user1428720 - if you change it to if else, then it starts to be correct - you would be comparing pointers rather than string content, and you might miss all the matches if any input strings come from data rather than from string literals in the same compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

although you can't compare strings directly the way you want, there's a way you can use dictionaries and defines/enums to engage a switch (see what I did there):

```
enum choices { LIST, ADD, DELETE, WRITE, QUIT, INVALID };

int
getchoice(char *input)
{
    static struct choices {
        enum choices val;
        const char *string;
    } choices [] = {
        { LIST, "list" },
        { ADD, "add" },
        { DELETE, "delete" },
        { WRITE, "write" },
        { QUIT, "quit" },
        { -1, NULL }
    };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; choices[i].val != -1; i++)
        if (strcmp(input, choices[i].string) == 0)
            break;
    if (choices[i].val == -1)
        return INVALID;
    return (choices[i].val);
}
```

and then for your switch statement:

```
switch (getchoice(choice)) {
case LIST:
case ADD:
case WRITE:
case DELETE:
case INVALID:
default:
    printf("Invalid\n");
    break;
case QUIT:
    exit(1);
}
```

caveat emptor, as this hasn't been run through a compiler, but the general idea should be clear enough to adapt to your specific case(s).

Answer (score 1):

Also, since you don't use `break` other than in the `default` case, you'll "drop" through to the default case automatically (even if your input `choice` matched "list", "add", "delete" and "write")

Comment: i forgot to mention the printf function before that. sorry

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

yes, you can call `exit()` anywhere, including inside a switch-case statement.

But that code has many issues, see my comment at the question itself.